# Add button dynamically (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I want to make pagination with jquery and Ajax.
The first where I'm stumbling on is how I can add a button

```
<div class="btn-group" id="pagination_group">
        <button class="btn" disabled="disabled">First</button>
        <button class="btn" disabled="disabled">Prev</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="p1">1</button>
        <button class="btn" id="p2">2</button>
        <button class="btn" id="p3">3</button>
        <button class="btn" id="p4">4</button>
        <button class="btn" id="p5">5</button>
        <button class="btn" id="next">Next</button>
        <button class="btn" id="last">Last</button>
    </div>
```

Something with append()? 
But how to get it it the right place?
The idea is after click on Next remove btn with id="p1" ( that's no problem) and add button with id="p6" between button5 and button Next.

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly several ways to accomplish this. See this [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ey6ww/5/)

Comment: Thank you. It is complete solution (at least what I nedeed for the moment).

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    $("#p1").remove();
    $("#next").before($('<button class="btn" id="p6">6</button>'));
})
```

Comment: I think you may remove the button that is after prev-button, because there won't be a "#p1" element for second time of clicking next button.

Comment: yeah, but I just answered wat was exectly asked for..I know this is not gonna work in general..cuz in that case he needs to change `p6` and `p1` info with preper variables..