# Add a div with text & link button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, addition

I want to add some text and an asp: button inside a Div using jQuery.

Code:

```
Hi,  <p> Are you sure you want to go ahead</p><p>Please ignore this warning if this is not the first time you are logging in</p>
<asp:button ID="btnProceed" runat="server" Text="Proceed"></asp:button>
```

Implementation:

```
jQ('#proceedDiv').append("<div> Hi,  <p> Are you sure you want to go ahead</p><p>Please ignore this warning if this is not the first time you are logging in</p> <asp:button ID="btnProceed" runat="server" Text="Proceed"></asp:button></div>");
```

but i am getting an error saying expected '('

That error is where button code starts. 
With alone text(and not button control) the code works fine. Can someone help me to fix it ?

Comment: Try to escape double apostrophe inside append-> \"

Comment: do you mean like this:  <asp:Button ID=\"lnkGoback1\" runat=\"server\"  ? it doesnot work. Any other way it should hv been done ?

Comment: Try switching them to single quotes instead: `<asp:button ID='btnProceed' runat='server' Text='Proceed'>`

Comment: You seem to be confusing server-side and client-side technologies. `<asp:button>` is a server-side component that renders to HTML markup in the page. jQuery allows you to modify that markup. Adding an `<asp:button>` element from the client side won't achieve anything, you should add the actual markup generated by the component instead.

Comment: Then how can I add a button using jQuery ?

Comment: The same way you're adding `<div>` and `<p>` elements in your current code. Or maybe see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762598/add-button-dynamically-jquery).

Comment: Well thanks. I found a work around. This helps:  var $ctrl = jQ('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button', name: 'btn', value: 'Button' }).addClass("Button"); jQ("#proceedDiv").append($ctrl);

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape your quotes...

```
<asp:button ID="btnProceed" runat="server" Text="Proceed">
```

needs to become

```
<asp:button ID=\"btnProceed\" runat=\"server\" Text=\"Proceed\">
```

Also note that

```
<button onclick="doSomething()">Click Me</button>
```